# Элементы не выстраиваются в ряд

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Элементы выстраиваются в колонку, а не в ряд. Что я делаю неправильно?

```css
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6. Team section css Start
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.st_team_section {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.team_cover {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.team_box {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.team_thumb {
  position: relative;
  perspective-origin: left center;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: left center;
  perspective: 400px;
  -webkit-perspective: 400px;
}

.team_thumb img {
  display: inline-block;
}

.team_thumb .team_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.95);
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.480, -0.050, 0.535, 1.370);
  -moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.480, -0.050, 0.535, 1.370);
  -o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.480, -0.050, 0.535, 1.370);
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.480, -0.050, 0.535, 1.370);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(45deg);
}

.team_overlay .team_desc {
  padding: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.team_desc h4 {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 25px 0 4px;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.team_desc h5 {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #B0BEC5;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.team_desc p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #dddddd;
  line-height: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-line-clamp: 3;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
}


/*========== social icons css ===========*/

.social_icon {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 9px 0 0;
}

.social_icon li {
  float: left;
}

.social_icon li a {
  margin: 3px;
  float: left;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #B0BEC5;
  font-size: 17px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  perspective-origin: center;
}

.social_icon li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 2px solid #B0BEC5;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.social_icon li a:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}


/*========== social icons css ===========*/

.team_box:hover .team_overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.team_box:hover .team_desc h4,
.team_box:hover .team_desc h5,
.team_box:hover .team_desc p,
.team_box:hover .social_icon {
  animation: fromleft 1s 1 both;
  -webkit-animation: fromleft 1s 1 both;
  -moz-animation: fromleft 1s 1 both;
}

.team_box:hover .team_desc h5 {
  animation-delay: .3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: .3s;
}

.team_box:hover .team_desc p {
  animation-delay: .6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: .6s;
}

.team_box:hover .social_icon {
  animation-delay: .9s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .9s;
  -moz-animation-delay: .9s;
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6. Team section css End
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Team section Start -->
<div class="st_team_section top_pad_100">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- section heading start -->
      <div class="section_heading">
        <div class="inline_block">
          <h2>Our Team</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- section heading start -->
      <div class="team_cover">
        <!-- team first start -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <div class="team_box fromright wow" data-wow-delay=".4s">
            <div class="team_thumb">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/270x348" class="img-responsive" alt="thumb">
              <div class="team_overlay">
                <div class="team_desc">
                  <div>
                    <h4>John Doe</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <h5>Web Designer</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content .</p>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="social_icon">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- team first end -->
        <!-- team second start -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <div class="team_box fromright wow">
            <div class="team_thumb">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/270x348" class="img-responsive" alt="thumb">
              <div class="team_overlay">
                <div class="team_desc">
                  <div>
                    <h4>Emily Taylor</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <h5>Graphic Designer</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content .</p>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="social_icon">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- team second end -->
        <!--  team third start -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <div class="team_box fromleft wow">
            <div class="team_thumb">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/270x348" class="img-responsive" alt="thumb">
              <div class="team_overlay">
                <div class="team_desc">
                  <div>
                    <h4>Marry Doe</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <h5>UI Designer</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content .</p>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="social_icon">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- team third end -->
        <!-- team fourth start-->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <div class="team_box fromleft wow" data-wow-delay=".4s">
            <div class="team_thumb">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/270x348" class="img-responsive" alt="thumb">
              <div class="team_overlay">
                <div class="team_desc">
                  <div>
                    <h4>Alex Smith</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <h5>Web Developer</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content .</p>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="social_icon">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- team fourth end -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Team section End -->
```

Answer (score 1):

`col-` должны распологаться внутри `.row`

Добавьте класс `.row` - `<div class="row team_cover">`

Пример

```css
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6. Team section css Start
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.st_team_section {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.team_cover {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.team_box {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.team_thumb {
  position: relative;
  perspective-origin: left center;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: left center;
  perspective: 400px;
  -webkit-perspective: 400px;
}

.team_thumb img {
  display: inline-block;
}

.team_thumb .team_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.95);
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.480, -0.050, 0.535, 1.370);
  -moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.480, -0.050, 0.535, 1.370);
  -o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.480, -0.050, 0.535, 1.370);
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.480, -0.050, 0.535, 1.370);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(45deg);
}

.team_overlay .team_desc {
  padding: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.team_desc h4 {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 25px 0 4px;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.team_desc h5 {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #B0BEC5;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.team_desc p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #dddddd;
  line-height: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-line-clamp: 3;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
}


/*========== social icons css ===========*/

.social_icon {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 9px 0 0;
}

.social_icon li {
  float: left;
}

.social_icon li a {
  margin: 3px;
  float: left;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #B0BEC5;
  font-size: 17px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  perspective-origin: center;
}

.social_icon li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 2px solid #B0BEC5;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.social_icon li a:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}


/*========== social icons css ===========*/

.team_box:hover .team_overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.team_box:hover .team_desc h4,
.team_box:hover .team_desc h5,
.team_box:hover .team_desc p,
.team_box:hover .social_icon {
  animation: fromleft 1s 1 both;
  -webkit-animation: fromleft 1s 1 both;
  -moz-animation: fromleft 1s 1 both;
}

.team_box:hover .team_desc h5 {
  animation-delay: .3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: .3s;
}

.team_box:hover .team_desc p {
  animation-delay: .6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: .6s;
}

.team_box:hover .social_icon {
  animation-delay: .9s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .9s;
  -moz-animation-delay: .9s;
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6. Team section css End
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Team section Start -->
<div class="st_team_section top_pad_100">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- section heading start -->
      <div class="section_heading">
        <div class="inline_block">
          <h2>Our Team</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- section heading start -->
      <div class="row team_cover">
        <!-- team first start -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <div class="team_box fromright wow" data-wow-delay=".4s">
            <div class="team_thumb">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/270x348" class="img-responsive" alt="thumb">
              <div class="team_overlay">
                <div class="team_desc">
                  <div>
                    <h4>John Doe</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <h5>Web Designer</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content .</p>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="social_icon">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- team first end -->
        <!-- team second start -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <div class="team_box fromright wow">
            <div class="team_thumb">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/270x348" class="img-responsive" alt="thumb">
              <div class="team_overlay">
                <div class="team_desc">
                  <div>
                    <h4>Emily Taylor</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <h5>Graphic Designer</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content .</p>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="social_icon">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- team second end -->
        <!--  team third start -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <div class="team_box fromleft wow">
            <div class="team_thumb">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/270x348" class="img-responsive" alt="thumb">
              <div class="team_overlay">
                <div class="team_desc">
                  <div>
                    <h4>Marry Doe</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <h5>UI Designer</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content .</p>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="social_icon">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- team third end -->
        <!-- team fourth start-->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <div class="team_box fromleft wow" data-wow-delay=".4s">
            <div class="team_thumb">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/270x348" class="img-responsive" alt="thumb">
              <div class="team_overlay">
                <div class="team_desc">
                  <div>
                    <h4>Alex Smith</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <h5>Web Developer</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content .</p>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="social_icon">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- team fourth end -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Team section End -->
```

Comment: спасибо огромное! невероятно глупая ошибка, которая стоила огромного количества времени!